# Excel 2016 - Consolidating two pivot tables with quotient

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have two very large pivot tables in Excel 2016 that are set up like this:

```
Table 1: 
Category | Total_count
A | 15000
B | 14500
C | 10000
D | 8000

Table 2: 
Category | Count
C | 6000
A | 12000
D | 3000
B | 2000
```

So the first pivot table has the total count of each category and the second table has the actual count of each category in my data. Now I want to normalize this data for future use by dividing the count from table 2 with the total count in table 1:

```
Table2.count / Table1.total_count
```

So what I would like to get as an output using the values of this example is:

```
Output table: 
Category | Normalized count
A | 0.8
B | 0.138 
C | 0.6
D | 0.375
```

I know it is possible to consolidate two pivot tables in Excel 2016, but when using consolidate there is no Quotient function. Is this possible using an Excel function?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have Excel 2016 you have both PowerQuery (a data mashup tool that allows you to mashup data from separate tables among other things) and the DataModel (that allows you to write 'Measures' using an Excel-like formula language called DAX). Both of these things will allow you to do what you seek. Give Google a spin using those terms and you should be able to muddle your way through fairly easily.

If I get time later today I might write up some instructions here, but I suggest meanwhile see if you can't work out how these two tools can help... there's no substitute for self research to get to grips with them, and they are awesome :-)